# MVC Web Role Post Build Event

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to copy two files to the bin directory to a Windows Azure Cloud Services deployement, I added the below Post-Build event script to the MVCWebRoleCore project properties:

```
copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)lib\SqlServerSpatial.dll" "$(TargetDir)SqlServerSpatial.dll"
copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)lib\SqlServerSpatial110.dll" "$(TargetDir)SqlServerSpatial110.dll"
```

Everything looks good locally and the two files are copied, but on Windows Azure the files are not there in the bin directory, (I checked the cloud deployment using RDC to make sure), What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy, it doesn't care what files are in your `BIN` folder. It cares about what files your `CSPROJ` project file specifies as part of the project deployment. If these are dependencies in your `References` list, just make sure `Copy Local` is set to `True` and they'll be deployed.

Comment: i have also put the dll files under the root folder and that was it

Comment: Excepting of course if they're in the GAC on your build machine, in which case Copy Local is ignored.